VirtualBox host only adapter interface doesn't get an IP address in Oracle Linux 7, and wired connection 1 with ipv4 automatic dhcp failed to connect


I want to use Oracle Virtual Box to do a test of connecting CentOS that has been created and connected to Data Studio from Windows. The first thing I did was set up to have IPv4 changed to automatic (DHCP). After setting it up, I tried to reconnect the network from the wired connection, but it couldn't connect. The adapter I tried was host-only

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
